# Getting null error although firebase reference is ok -

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()` when my code reaches the valueEventListener although while debugging, it seems to me that the child value is not null.

Here is the image of the code:

[image: code image]

This is how the database looks like:

[image: database image]

Solved the problem by completely deleting the code and starting again. This time I checked with firebase github and I did it like this(mostly the same thing? i wish i knew what was wrong with my first code):

```
userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener userListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //Get user object
        currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, "Failed to load post.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
userReference.addValueEventListener(userListener);
```

Comment: Please try to put your code as text and not image.

Comment: Sorry, newbie with stackoverflow.. should I edit now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String country = dataSnapshot.child("country").getValue(String.class);
        String city = dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, country + " / " + city);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be the exact `country` and `city` of your user.

Comment: Yeah! I edited my post at the same time. It surely works like this :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The only place, in the code shown, where you could get a NPE with that message is in the call:

```
...child("users").child(uid);
```

So I'd check that uid variable, work out a way to deal with such scenario `(uid == null)`.

Comment: But if I log the uid before or after that line it prints the exact uid I need..it's not null..

Answer (score 0):

Use `getValue(String.class)` instead of `getValue().toString();`

Answer (score 0):

You are using unnecessary for loop.You already know what user uid is.Remove for loop then try again.

Comment: Thanks. The loop really was unnecessary, but removing it didn't solve my problem either